# How to see the content of the build directory in a Java Vaadin 7 Web application project Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, vaadin

how can I see the content of the build directory inside a Vaadin 7 project created with Eclipse? I have tried the following steps based on another post here on SO (actually referred to the bin/ directory of a Java project), but it hasn't work for me:

> 1) Find your class output folder in the “Project explorer” window.
>   This is usually called “bin” or “target” for Maven projects;
>
> 2) Right-click this folder and click “Properties”;
>
> 3) Tick the “Derived” checkbox and click “OK”;

I have unchecked the "Derived" checkbox but yet I can't see the content of build dir. How can I see its content?

Answer (score 0):

If by "build directory" you mean mean the place where the compiled .class files are put, then just

right-click on project > "Properties" > "Java Build Path" > "Source" tab > "Default output folder"

Regards

Comment: Yes it is, thank you, anyway can I make it available in the project, I mean I would like to access that pat from the Eclispe's Project Explorer, is it possible?

Comment: that should be visible by default.
For example i have "[project_name]/build/classes" and i see folder "build" in my project explorer, right under the libraries

Comment: Yes the folder build is visible to me too, but not the content, i.e. I can't see the build/classes folder inside of it or if I put an image (using command line) inside the build directory, I can't see it in Project Explorer. Is it possible to make this resources inside build/ visible?